# Authorization header first character incorrect error, results in 401

Tags: angular, oauth, adal, bearer-token, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using adal to wrap my app and access it through oauth/Azure. 
Using an interceptor but am getting an error message 401 depending if I use the following code in setHeaders. 
    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.oauthService.getAccessToken()}`
But the following line of code works and does not produce any errors.
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.oauthService.getAccessToken()

Could somebody explain what's wrong in in the first Authoriztion-thing? Where does the extra character comes from that creates a 401 instead?

I've tried changing the line 
    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.oauthService.getAccessToken()}`
in many ways but nothing works with this line.

```js
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {
}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            // Authorization: `Bearer ${this.oauthService.getAccessToken()}`
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.oauthService.getAccessToken()
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Does `this.oauthService.getAccessToken()` return a string or observable?

Comment: Could you also specify, what incorrect first character? How does the deformed header look?

Comment: 1) It looks like a string.
2) I don't know how to receive the header and look at it on front end. Via some errormessage I got something like "wrong at the first character"